# Choose image from photo album in Cordova windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

Can anyone please let me know how to choose image from photo album and get the file-uri or base-64 delivered thru call back.

I am able to take a picture from camera but facing problem while picking an image from photoalbum. I am using below code to choose an image but right after choosing an image the app navigates back to the home screen(index.html) by giving this warning on console "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337".

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
                                     {
                                         quality: 50,
                                         destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                         mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                                         sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType = {
                                             PHOTOLIBRARY: 1,
                                             CAMERA: 0,
                                             SAVEDPHOTOALBUM: 2
                                         },
                                         mediaType: Camera.MediaType = {
                                             PICTURE: 1,    // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
                                             VIDEO: 0,      // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
                                             ALLMEDIA: 2   // allow selection from all media types
                                         },
                                         allowEdit: 1,
                                         width: compRatio,
                                         height: compRatio
                                     });
```

Comment: As I know, this is a bug in the camera plugin. I'm waiting for the solution since many weeks, no luck. Let's put your comment here, if you want: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11295?filter=-3

Comment: Any alternative solution? All I need to do is choose images from photo album.